# 3ware 9650SE-24 Raid-50 stuck

Tags: degraded

One mornig after starting the NAS five drives were "Degraded". -The night before everything was fine.- The Raid-50 (Unit 3) is build up of three Raid-5 with seven disk each. All disk 2 TB.

Now Subunit 0 is OK. Subunit 1 has have three "Degraded" Disk. Subunit 2 has two "Degraded" disk

There are three disk spare.

First I have tried several Cli commands. But the 9650SE-24 only send Errors.
"Rebuild" did not start.

The "Rebuild" command with "3DM2" only answer: "(0x0B:0x0033) Unit busy: Faild to start Rebuild on Unit 3.

I have tried an other 9650SE-24. Nothing changed.
I have taken the 8 HDD out of the System an replaced them with new 8 HDD. Nothing changed. No other reaction on Rebuild command.
I have changed the motherboerd. Nothing changed.

Is there any other way to start Rebuild?´
Diag file:
https://c.gmx.net/@328120576243663662/Z3CPXaZzTpyxxZWVBgWD4w